# Keep Facebook access token always active

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I wonder how can I confidently keep my Facebook access token always active.

Is it enough to subscribe to token updates with `AccessTokenTracker`, or it's also/instead need to check token expiration before every call to API with `AccessToken.isExpired()` and then refresh token by `AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync(callback)`?

For example: would `AccessTokenTracker` bring new access token after app has started? It means, that token has been expired when app was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by checking up `AccessToken.isExpired()` before each call to Facebook API, and then call `AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync` if the token is expired